# How to run only specific directory using tox in pytest?

Tags: python, json, pytest, tox

[image: This is the structure of the test framework]

test_pytest.py is inside tests directory and it contains automated code (below methods) to test machine learning work flow.

```
 def test_workflow(caplog,test_name,test_params,test_step):,
 def test_upload_and_import_data(input_params, output_params,):,
 def test_feature_eng(input_params, output_params):,
 def test_auto_training(input_params, output_params, problem_type):,
 def test_get_prediction(input_params, output_params):
 def test_retraining(response):
 def delete_ai_service():
```

QA_test directory is inside test_data->tests.
It contains json files, giving inputs and expected outputs for above methods for differents datasets.
As a example,

{

```
"Car_prices dataset" : [
    {
        "dataImport": {
            "input": {
                "test_filename": "carprices.csv",
                "file_location": "AWS"
            },
            "expectedOutput": {
                "result" : "success"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "featureEngineering": {
            "input": {
            "column": "MSRP",
            "waitTime": 60,
            "problemType" : "auto"
    
            },
            "expectedOutput": {
    "result" : "Completed"
            }
        }
    },
    '
    '
    '
```

]

}

This is the existing tox file.

```
[tox]
   envlist = py38

[testenv]
deps =
   pytest
   pytest-html
   pytest-sugar
   pytest-logger
   allure-pytest
   pytest-xdist
   pytest_steps
   datetime
   oauth2client
   gspread
   aiclub
commands =
   pytest -s -v -k _workflow  --html=test_report.html --alluredir=allure-results/ -n auto --dist=loadfile
   allure serve allure-results
```

Currently when I type tox in terminal it runs the entire test suite running all workflow for all datasets.
How can I run the test workflow only for testcases(json files) in QA_test directory?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `posargs` feature of `tox` - this let's you specify a specific command whenever you want.

You use `pytest` as a testrunner. The `-k` option specifies a pattern of tests you want to run.

Instead of hardcoding it to `_workflow`, you need to do something like

```
commands = 
     pytest -s -v {posargs:-k _workflow} ...
```

Then you can run a single test via

```
tox -- -k singleTest
```

If you just run `tox`, the default (`-k _workflow`) is used.

Everything behind the double dash gets passed into the command - in this case into `pytest`.

The `tox` feature `posargs` is documented at https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/general.html

For `pytest` have a look at https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests

Comment: https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#substitutions-for-positional-arguments-in-commands

Comment: ERROR: InvocationError for command 'D:\QA\test-framework\python-client\.tox\py38\Scripts\pytest.EXE' -s -v -k QA_tests --html=test_report.html --alluredir=allure-results/ -n auto --dist=loadfile (exited with code 5)

Comment: @J.G. when I used "pytest -s -v {posargs:-k _workflow}  --html=test_report.html --alluredir=allure-results/ -n auto --dist=loadfile" and run "tox -- -k QA_tests" in terminal gave the above error .

Comment: @ShelomiPriskila Unfortunately, I cannot see an obvious problem. When I experience similar problems, I try to make the command as simple as possible, make sure it works, and then add the other options back, one by one. Maybe start with `commands = commands = pytest {posargs:-k _workflow}` ...

Comment: @J.G. For "pytest {posargs:-k _workflow}" command also it gives same invocation error

Comment: Oh my :-) I just googled for "exit code 5" - and this is an error of `pytest` - which says: "no test run". So you need to make sure your expression after `-k` actually collects a test :-)